# Changing ngModel binding inside loop

Tags: typescript, angular

Sorry, but I don't know how to properly describe this problem.

I'm trying to output a form, that loops through an array of object keys and displays input fields depending on how many properties a object has.

For example:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Data</legend>
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="#key of dataKeys"
            <label>{{ key }}</label>
            <input 
                [(ngModel)]="data." + key
                class="form-control"
                ngControl="key"
                #key="ngForm">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And I want it to evaluate to this:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Data</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>id</label>
            <input 
                [(ngModel)]="data.id"
                class="form-control"
                ngControl="id"
                #id="ngForm">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>score</label>
            <input 
                [(ngModel)]="data.score"
                class="form-control"
                ngControl="score"
                #score="ngForm">
        </div>
        ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I know that it can't work like I have it in the template at the moment, but I just can't figure out how to make it work properly.
I thought maybe a custom direction would be a solution, but even after scouring through all the google results I could find to this I can't make it work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
[(ngModel)]="data[key]"
```

Comment: Oh wow... It does work. Thanks a lot! Thats embarassing that I didn't think of the alternate syntax to access object properties. But how do I do it with "ngControl" and the variable that ngForm is assigned to?

Comment: For template variables you have to use static names `#xxx` has to be added to the template as is, these names can't be generated. I haven't found in the source where `ngControl` is read and if it is read in a way that it can be dynamically generated like `[ngControl]="xxx + 'yyy'"`. Just try it.